# SNSEvent Object's getRecords() returning null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I've created and deployed a simple Lambda function written in Java.  I seem to have a couple of issues.

The first is, the SNSEvent object's getRecords() method call returns null and I can't figure out why.  I tried testing it from within SNS, but that doesn't work because of the second problem....

The second is, Cloudwatch does not seem to be receiving any logs from the Lambda function.  Without Cloudwatch logs, I have no way of seeing any logs when testing from SNS...

Below is the relevant code from the Lambda function.

```
public void articleHandler(SNSEvent articleMsg, Context context) {
    LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

    if (articleMsg.getRecords() == null) {
        logger.log("Getrecords is null");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    for (SNSEvent.SNSRecord msg : articleMsg.getRecords()) {
        try {
            logger.log("Getting headline records");
            JsonObject headline = getMessageAsJsonObject(msg.getSNS().getMessage());
            if (headline.has("link") && headline.get("link").isJsonPrimitive() && headline.get("link").getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {
                headline.addProperty("body", getArticleBody(headline.get("link").getAsString()));
                logger.log(headline.toString());
            } else {
                throw new InvalidJSONException("\"link\" field either doesn't exist or is not a String primitive", headline.toString());
            }
        } catch (InvalidJSONException ex) {
            logger.log(ex.toString());
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | TikaException ex) {
            logger.log(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my pom file.  I tried making the aws-lambda-java-core and aws-lambda-java-events the same version, but that didn't change anything and I put it back to the 1.0.0 and 1.1.0 versions because that's what worked in a different Lambda function.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I've been using the following JSON as a test (from within Lambda) call to this Lambda function, I got it straight from the SNS Json Generator.

```
{
  "default": "{\"id\":1636,\"unread\":true,\"marked\":false,\"published\":false,\"updated\":1454242851,\"is_updated\":false,\"title\":\"Dubai tourism allure undiminished by hotel fire: tourism chief\",\"link\":\"http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/Reuters/worldNews/~3/aOd7O2wZCwc/story01.htm\",\"feed_id\":\"3\",\"tags\":[\"worldnews\"],\"excerpt\":\"&hellip;\",\"labels\":[],\"feed_title\":\"Reuters: World News\",\"comments_count\":0,\"comments_link\":\"\",\"always_display_attachments\":false,\"author\":\"\",\"score\":0,\"note\":null,\"lang\":\"en\"}",
  "lambda": "{\"id\":1636,\"unread\":true,\"marked\":false,\"published\":false,\"updated\":1454242851,\"is_updated\":false,\"title\":\"Dubai tourism allure undiminished by hotel fire: tourism chief\",\"link\":\"http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/Reuters/worldNews/~3/aOd7O2wZCwc/story01.htm\",\"feed_id\":\"3\",\"tags\":[\"worldnews\"],\"excerpt\":\"&hellip;\",\"labels\":[],\"feed_title\":\"Reuters: World News\",\"comments_count\":0,\"comments_link\":\"\",\"always_display_attachments\":false,\"author\":\"\",\"score\":0,\"note\":null,\"lang\":\"en\"}"
}
```

Since Cloudwatch is not reporting any logs, I can only see what the Lambda console reports:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Process exited before completing request"
}
```

If I remove the if (articleMsg.getRecords() == null) statement from the function, I get the following error in the Lambda console.

```
{   "errorMessage": "java.lang.NullPointerException",   "errorType": "java.lang.NullPointerException",   "stackTrace": [
    "com.myapp.articlehandler.LambdaHandler.articleHandler(LambdaHandler.java:35)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)"] 
}
```

Line 35 in LambdaHandler.java (the code pasted above) refers to:

```
for (SNSEvent.SNSRecord msg : articleMsg.getRecords()) {
```

Finally, when I click on the link in the error "Execution result: failed (logs)" to see the Cloudwatch logs, Cloudwatch opens and gives me the following error and does not show any logs for this Lambda function:

> There was an error loading Log Streams. Please try again by refreshing
>   this page.

It doesn't appear that the two problems are related, though I can't be sure.

Does anyone have any suggestions for either / both issues?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue while triggering lambdas for dynamo db

Comment: @Tisha I'm sorry, I don't remember what the fix was.  I should have posted a follow-up....All I can say is, usually when I had a problem like this, it was because there was a problem with the JSON being sent to the Lambda function.